# context window of frames speech recognition

Tags: deep-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

In many speech recognition paper, I see this term "context window of frame". I am not sure about that but it seem like u take a frame x from a utterance, and you concatenation this frame with 5 previous frames and 5 future frames. And the label for this context window is the center frame. Am I right?

Thank you

(Btw the number 5 is just an example)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this term gained popularity starting from application of Deep Neural Networks (DNN) to Automatic Speech Recognition. For example, "11 frame acoustic context window" means you concatenate feature vectors of 5 previous and 5 future frames to current frame's vector. But the label is still center frame's label. Using context windows improved performance of DNN models, but not previously used HMMs (Hidden Markov Models).

Please refer to [this](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/38131.pdf) article for more info.